# Best Time of the Day to Visit N Hollywood Blvd (Walk of Fame Stars)

Tags: california, hollywood

We are visiting California and wanted to go to Hollywood and visit the walk of fame (star walk). Does anyone know what time of the day is the best to do this? Since it might be very busy and crowded.

Answer (score 2):

Go there at sunrise, when there will be few other people and the hand and foot print shadows will be deep.